# Syncfusion Range slider space

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to add the syncfusion range slider in my xamarin form application.
everything is okay but there is a small problem.
there is a blank space in the top and bottom side of the range slider.
i don't know from where it's coming.
i just placed the slider inside a stacklayout that's it.

```
  <range:SfRangeSlider  x:Name="rangeslider_salary" Minimum="1000" Maximum="300000"  RangeStart="3000" RangeEnd="100000" TickPlacement="None" ShowRange="True" ShowValueLabel="False" Orientation="Horizontal" LabelColor="#ED4350" KnobColor="#ED4350" TrackSelectionColor="#ED4350" ToolTipTextColor="#ED4350" RangeChanging="Rangeslider_salary_RangeChanging"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figured out?

Answer (score -1):

We have analysed your requirement and have created a simple sample with SfRangeSlider Control. Please have the sample from the below link.

Sample Link: [RangeSlider](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/203367/ze/RangeSlider203367-1063027305)

Please check the sample and let us know if you have any concern.

Regards,

Rabhia Beham K[Syncfusion].